# NotificationManager to display upload progress and repeat in case of failure

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm using a Notification to display the upload progresss, however I need to be able to retry the upload by clicking on the notification or adding a retry button to it. The notification is controlled by an AsyncTask that receives data from an Activity, so I need to keep all this data to retry the upload.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could just add an intent to the notification to start some activity.

Comment: How about keeping the data?